# Filtering data from ruby gem firebase realtime database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure in my firebase realtime database:

```
{objects => 
  {
  "69260"=>
        {
            "proposer_nickname"=>"william", 
            "votes" => 2
        },
  "04690"=>
        {
            "proposer_nickname"=>"john", 
            "votes" => 3
        }
  }
}
```

I'm using the following ruby gem in order to query Firebase:
https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby

I'm trying to filter by one of the fields (proposer_nickname).
So here is my query:

```
firebase = Firebase::Client.new('https://<my_project>.firebaseio.com/objects', private_key_json_string)

response = firebase.get('', {'orderBy' => 'proposer_nickname', 'equalTo' => 'william' })
```

Problem if I do that, I get all objects. No filter is applied to the ones with child field 'proposer_nickname' = 'william'

I also added an Index as mentionned here:
[add an index to your Firebase security rules:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)

```
"objects": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid != null",
      ".indexOn": ["proposer_nickname"]
    }
```

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the `order_by` and `equal_to` names from, but from [this spec](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby/blob/master/spec/firebase_spec.rb#L40-L47) it seems the Ruby gem uses `orderBy` and `equalTo` (which is the same as the Firebase REST API uses).

Comment: I updated my question. You're right however it doesn't work better :(

Comment: Good to hear you got it working in the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work...
Thanks Frank van Puffelen for pointing me to the spec. It got me in the right direction.

So in case somebody wants to do the same, here is what you need to do:

- Don't forget to add your field in the index as mentionned at the bottom of the question
- put your query as follow (my error was in the quotes !):

```
response = firebase.get('', {:orderBy => '"proposer_nickname"', :equalTo => '"william"' })
```

Hope it will save time to sombeody

Comment: If you are looking to use a string instead of '"william"', convert it to json.  `response = firebase.get('', {:orderBy => '"proposer_nickname"', :equalTo => strName.to_json}) `